# How to sort a List<string> character by character?

Tags: c#, list, sorting

Below code;

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    list.Add("using System;");
    list.Add("using System.Linq;");
    list.Add("using System.Collections.Generic;");
    Console.WriteLine(RandomPassword());
}
```

How can I always get the sorting result below?

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Linq;
```

I had tried

```
List = List.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToList();
```

But doesn't work.

Comment: In C# `List` is a type, and in your code `list` is an instance of the `List` type.  So the code you wrote should not have compiled as you can not assign a value to a type.   `But doesn't work` is so very not helpful in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: Just do `list.Sort();` for an in-place sort.

Comment: Second, if you actually meant `list = list.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToArray();`, why are you casting to an array when the data type you are assigning to is a `List<string>` ?   You have some major issues with the code you posted, unrelated to your question, that need to be resolved before we can help you.  Please read the faq on how to ask, and provide a minimum **verifiable** example.

Comment: Please replace the *"But doesn't work"* with an actual problem description

Comment: I had updated my code per @Sam's input, yes, this is my first time using this platform and while trying to make it right I type the coding by hand, therefore I missed the cast. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `;` comes after `.` in the [Unicode character set](https://unicode-table.com/en/) which is used for sorting.

```
list.OrderBy(x => x)

    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System;                      <=== ; comes after dot
```

If you convert all `;` characters to `!` (which comes before `.` in Unicode) then strings containing semicolons will move upwards.

```
list.OrderBy(x => x.Replace(";", "!"))

    using System;                      <=== ! comes before dot
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to tell which comes after which? Eg, ! . ;

Comment: You mean apart from looking at the Unicode character set link, lowest number first? Try this: `if ("!" < ".") { Console.WriteLine("yay"); }`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want an array at the end, rather than a list, using this should give you a correctly ordered array:

```
string[] mySortedArray = list.OrderBy(x => x.Replace(";", string.Empty)).ToArray()
```

If you require a list, based on your original code:

```
list = list.OrderBy(x => x.Replace(";", string.Empty)).ToList()
```

There are two things to note here - firstly, unlike your code, this sort is ascending, not descending; secondly, to give you the result you require you need to strip out the semi-colons while sorting, otherwise they will skew the results, causing the item you wish to be first to come last.

As pointed out in the comments though, there are a number of other issues present in the code you posted.

Comment: Wow, thanks, this is exactly what I need, you are such a great help Diado, your answer is very helpful, I had marked your solution as well. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a custom comparer:

```
class AssemblyNameComparer : IComparer<string>
    {
        private readonly IComparer<string> _baseComparer;
        public AssemblyNameComparer(IComparer<string> baseComparer)
        {
            _baseComparer = baseComparer;
        }

        public int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            string xTrimmed = RemoveSemicolon(x);
            string yTrimmed = RemoveSemicolon(y);
            return _baseComparer.Compare(xTrimmed, yTrimmed);
        }

        string RemoveSemicolon(string x)
        {
            return Regex.Replace(x, ";", "");
        }
    }
```

This will provide sorting based on 'stripped' values, like:

> "using System.Collections.Generic"

and call Sort() method:

```
        list.Sort(new AssemblyNameComparer(StringComparer.CurrentCulture));
```

Sort is done in-place, there's no need to assign result anywhere.

Comment: The issue with replacing the periods in addition to semi-colons is that it will also skew the results. For instance, if you had:
`using Net.Services.Anchors;
using Net.Services.Communication;
using Net.ServicesBinder.Helpers`
or similar, `Net.ServicesBinder.Helpers` will appear between the other two, which seems illogical.

Comment: Like Diado says above I don't think you want to replace ; and . with an empty string, if you make them both the same though (e.g. replace ; with .) then you would have his example in the right order

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my answer. In given example I think going for custom comparer might be an overkill, but I'll leave it if anyone needs a solution for more complicated case.